# How can I display image from props with GraphQL? Can display image url but not the image itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a wordpress cms with a GraphQL plugin on the backend.
The front end is react.
This a page component that is used for all pages in my wordpress.

My app seems to break completely when I try to render the image.

I can print the image src url just fine.

I'm using this boilerplate code and added in my own GraphQL endpoint for the data.

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
        import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
        import gql from 'graphql-tag';
        import { sanitize } from '../commons/HtmlSanitizer';

        class Page extends Component {


          render() {
            const props = this.props;

            return (
              <div className="page">


                <h1>{(props.data.page.childPages) ? props.data.page.childPages.edges[0].node.title : '-'}</h1>

                <div id="page-content" className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: (props.data.page) ? sanitize(props.data.page.content) : ''
                }}></div>
              </div>
            );
          }

          componentDidUpdate() {
            let pageContent = document.getElementById('page-content');
            let links = Array.from(pageContent.querySelectorAll('a'));
            links.map( (node) => node.onclick = this.onLinkClicked.bind(this) );
          }

          onLinkClicked(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.props.history.push(event.currentTarget.pathname);
          }
        }

        const GetPageBySlug = gql`
          query petPageBySlug($slug: String) {
            page: pageBy(uri:$slug) {
              id
              title
              slug
              date
              content
              childPages{
                  edges{
                    node{
                      id
                      title
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }`;

        export default graphql(GetPageBySlug, {
          options: (props) => {

            let { slug, parent } = props.match.params;
            if (parent == "locations") {
              slug = `${parent}/${slug}`
            }
            if(parent == "pediatrics"){
              slug = `locations/${parent}/${slug}`
            }

            return {
              variables: {
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        })(Page);
```

Comment: What is the value of the sourceUrl while the data is still loading? Be sure your react component knows what it should render while there is no sourceUrl prop.

Comment: Also please post what breaks, ie: stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you're not checking to see if `props.data.page` exists, when you attempt to access `props.data.page.featuredImage`. When `props.data.page` is undefined, the code will crash, because you're trying to access a property on an undefined object. Make sure page exists (And perhaps even futher to make sure `props.data.page.featuredImage` exists as well):

```
render() {
    const props = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="page">  
        <h1>{(props.data.page) ? props.data.page.featuredImage.sourceUrl : '-'}</h1>

        {props.data.page && <img src={props.data.page.featuredImage.sourceUrl} alt={props.data.page.slug} />}

        <div id="page-content" className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: (props.data.page) ? sanitize(props.data.page.content) : ''
        }}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

See the docs for [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks @FrankerZ ... I'm trying to map through an array in {props.data.page.childPages.edges} and I get an error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childPages' of undefined

Comment: im trying to use a conditional<h1>{(props.data.page.childPages) ? props.data.page.childPages.edges[0].node.title : '-'}</h1>

Comment: Is this another error @TrimTrimm? (Not related to the code you posted in the original question)

Comment: I've updated my code to better reflect my question. It's the same error but on a different property. I'd like to map through the items in props.data.page.childPages.edge

Comment: Again, you're trying to access `childPages` on `props.data.page`. If `props.data.page` doesn't exist (is undefined), `props.data` wont exist. You HAVE to check each property of those that could be undefined, before trying to expand into them. If `props.data.page` may be undefined, but then after it's defined you have an expected structure, then you wont need to do: `props.data.page && props.data.page.childPages && props.data.page.childPages.edges && ...`.

Comment: Additionally, if this has answered your question, you should mark it as accepted (Using the checkmark to the left of the post). Followup questions/edits that turn this into an entirely different question are discouraged. You're encouraged to created another question, and refer to this one if it provides context.